# Can you bridge a Docker container to one specific host network while also using the conventional Docker-managed bridge at the same time?

Tags: docker

I want to run an application in a container that expects to be able to broadcast to other nodes on a network. The Docker host I want to run the container on is also serving as a router between two physical networks with different IP address ranges. (The router implements appropriate firewall rules for routing between the two networks as well. using the `DOCKER-USER` table.)

```
+-----------------+  eth0   +---------------+   eth1  +-----------------+
| 192.168.50.0/24 |  ---->  | DOCKER/ROUTER |  <----  | 192.168.60.0/24 |
+-----------------+         +---------------+         +-----------------+
```

The container's application needs to be able to communicate directly via broadcast UDP messages to nodes on 192.168.60.0/24 and receive unicast responses for those broadcasts, but should *not* broadcast to nodes on 192.168.50.0/24. The application (at least as of now) doesn't support "arbitrary" broadcast addresses - it uses the known IP address and netmask of the interfaces it sees. So if it sees `eth1`, it knows to send its broadcasts to `192.168.60.255` on specific ports.

I know that normally, when you run a Docker container, it'll be connected to a virtual Ethernet interface attached to a bridge interface. The bridge itself is not bridged to any host network interfaces, all of that is handled by the Docker daemon injecting rules into `iptables` as necessary. This is fine for the "admin" side of the app - the side that will provide a web UI for using the app. Thus, connections from 192.168.50.0/24 will be routed through to the container in the traditional sense.

What I want to do is connect a second virtual network to the container that *is* directly bridged to `eth1`. Thus, the container would appear to have two network interfaces - one virtual Ethernet interface on a 172.x.x.x network (managed by Docker in the conventional way), and a *second* virtual Ethernet which would be directly bridged to `eth1` and given an IP address on the `192.168.60.x` network as if it were an independent host there.

On `eth1`, I'll be running a DHCP server. The DHCP server will give out IPs to the devices in the range of e.g. `192.168.60.10 - 192.168.60.254`. I'd like the container to receive a *static IP* on this second interface, say `192.168.60.2`. (assuming the Docker host's IP on `eth1` is `192.168.50.1`)

Here's my questions:

- I've never dealt with multiple network interfaces in one container - is that even possible? Do you just specify multiple `--network` options? How does that work in `docker-compose` files?
- Can I create a bridge network in Docker itself that is always automatically bridged to a given host network? I could alternatively create the bridge outside of Docker and have it managed by, say, `networkmanager`, but then can I have Docker "use" that bridge, assigning the container's second virtual Ethernet to that bridge, automatically? (Basically, how do I tell Docker that the container should have a second `veth` interface, which should be bridged to interface `br0` which I manage outside of Docker?)
- How can I get Docker to give out the static IP I want the container to have to the virtual Ethernet interface?
- Other than having to manually configure the bridge, can any of this be set up in a `docker-compose` file? i.e. the name of the host network to bridge to, and the IP address to give the container on that network?

Alternatives I've considered:

- Using `host` is not acceptable here since I do *not* want the container to broadcast to `192.168.50.0/24`. If the container sees the Docker bridge network (the `172.x.x.x` network Docker manages) that is acceptable - broadcasting there won't be routed out to the LAN.
- Bringing up an entire extra host just to run Docker + this container (i.e. connecting another server to the `192.168.60.x` network) is way overkill for this project.

If it makes more sense, here is an imaginary Docker command (and related network setup) that would do what I want, if Docker used this imaginary syntax:

```
ip addr add dev eth0 192.168.50.1
brctl addbr br0
brctl addif br0 eth1
ip addr add dev br0 192.168.60.1/24
docker run -d --name mycontainer -p 8000:80 --network bridge --network lanbridge,if=br0,ip=192.168.60.2/24 mycontainer
# The result should be a container accessible via eth0 on port 8000, but also
# fully bridged to eth1 at layer 3 via 192.168.60.2
```